# Hibernate Persistentbag instead of ArrayList

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, jpa-2.0

does anyone have an idea on how to get an arrayList out of a OneToMany-realtionship?
Currently I get a persistentbag and the features/attributes are counterproductive for my application.

Consider following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOOS")
@NamedQuery(name = "Foo.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Foo r")
public class Foo implements Serializable, IKontingent {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Ba> baList;

@Transient
private boolean editable;


public boolean isEditable() {
    boolean editMode = true;

    if (this.getBaList() == null || this.getBaList().size() == 0) {
        editMode = false;
    }

    return editMode;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BAS")
@NamedQuery(name = "Ba.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM Ba o")
public class Ba implements Serializable, IKontingentWithParent {

/**
 * Generated
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1856655370465252150L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ba", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<MoreStuff> moreStuffList;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
private Foo foo;

@Transient
private long temporalLong;


public long getTemporalLong() {
    long sum = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(moreStuffList) == true ? 0L : this.getMoreStuffList().stream().collect(Collectors.summingLong(q -> q.getTemporalLong()));
    return sum;

}
```

Because of the persistentbag I can't get a correct temporalLong since it resolves to 0L.

Comment: i think you want set rather than list

Comment: Nearly same result, now it becomes a persistentSet with the same behaviour.